# Strange Nodal Analysis

Tags: homework, nodal-analysis

I have done the nodal analysis for the following question, and everything appears to have been done correctly as far as I can see. However, when I simulate the results I get values for the circuit which are wildly different.

Where would the error have been introduced? All sign conventions are followed and I've doubled checked the working out.

**Edit :  Ix = (v1-v2)/2  | This was not included in the diagram**
[image]

Comment: Is there a multiplication by `2` missing in middle equation ? The source is `2 ix`. `(V1 - V2)/2` is only `1ix` ? Also mark the reference direction of `ix` in the diagram. It seems to be marked 2 different ways in the current diagram.

Comment: Hi @AJN, I've edited Ix, it should have been (V1-V2)/2. And the dependent current should be 2Ix. 

I thought with regards to nodal analysis, we could specify the direction of the current (by default) to point inwards into a node, with the exception being currents that outright were pointing away from the node.

Comment: Does the original question have `ix` reference direction clearly marked ?

Comment: Yes, it does, it has it marked from left to right at the V1 node. The current is marked as moving from V1 to V2. 

But I don't think that would make a difference as I have remained consistent with the current directions. Furthermore, I tested the equation and removed the dependent current source and replaced it with an independent current source (9.6A) and it provides the correct answer. I find that very strange as no other change was made to the equation.

Comment: For node V1 why did you mark +12A and at the same time you give a "+" sign for (V1-V3)/4 as well? This current (V1 - V3) is leaving the node, the current is flowing from V1 to V3.

Comment: Hi @G36, I don't quite understand the question. But the reason why both of them have positive signage is that I have declared that they are both entering into V1. If they were leaving V1 then I would have negative. 

At each node I assume that the given node has the highest voltage that is why it's V1 - V3 and in V3 it is V3-V1.

Comment: And this why you are getting the wrong answer.  The "entring current" is (V3 - V1)/4 (flow into the V1 node) and the leaving current is (V1 - V3)/4 (flow out of the V1 node). Therefore by assuming that the given node has the highest voltage. This means that you have assumed that all current will be leaving the node.

Comment: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGEhY.png) is what I get. The numbers for the voltages don't seem to match yours.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your mistake is again the current direction.

For \$V_1\$ node you have wrote:
$$+12A + \frac{V_1 - V_2}{2\Omega}....= 0$$

As we can see from a circuit diagram the \$12A\$ current is entering the node(incoming current).
But we have a problem here because you decided to give a "+" for 2 ohms resistor current as well.

But this notation \$\frac{V_1 - V_2}{2\Omega}\$ imposes the current direction. And this current direction is from \$V_1\$ to \$V_3\$ (the current is flowing out of the node).

And here we have an error in your current direction assumption. And this is why you are getting the wrong answer.

The correct equation should look like this:

$$-12A + \frac{V_1 - V_2}{2\Omega} + \frac{V_1 - V_3}{4\Omega} = 0$$
$$\frac{V_2}{4\Omega} + \frac{V_2 - V_1}{2\Omega} + \frac{V_2 - V_3}{8\Omega} = 0$$
$$ 2\times\frac{V_1 - V_2}{2\Omega} + \frac{V_3 - V_1}{4\Omega} + \frac{V_3 - V_2}{8\Omega} = 0$$

Or like this (not recommended way):

$$+12A + \frac{V_2 - V_1}{2\Omega} + \frac{V_3 - V_1}{4\Omega} = 0$$
$$\frac{V_2}{4\Omega} + \frac{V_2 - V_1}{2\Omega} +\frac{V_2 - V_3}{8\Omega} = 0$$
$$ 2\times\frac{V_1 - V_2}{2\Omega} +\frac{V_3 - V_1}{4\Omega}+\frac{V_3 - V_2}{8\Omega} = 0$$

Comment: Wow, thank you. I confused myself, but you've explained it soo well. I now get it.